# How to get the coordinates for a selection bounding box in Gimp

Tags: gimp, crop, script, python

I'll make a rectangle selection in image. I have to read the left, right, up and down dimensions of this selected region in full image. The following image is an example of this.

[image]

**Edit:**

Can we print the following variables in the window or debug screen?

Units in mm.

```
L = X of Selection Bounding Box
U = Y of Selection Bounding Box
D = H of Image - (H of Selection Bounding Box + U)
R = W of Image - (W of Selection Bounding Box + L)
```

Answer (score 3):

This example image is 200px x 200px. If you don't know it, you can find the size by clicking *Image > Canvas Size*

[image]

The Crop Tool options show the X and Y position of the top left corner of the crop, and the X and Y size of the crop. So it's simple arithmetic to work out the distances.

Left = 33px

Up = 49px

Right = 200-33-129 = 38px

Down = 200-49-96 = 55px

Comment: You're right. But can Gimp do this automatically? Can a script be embedded in Gimp? Because I have a lot of pictures to do. Or is there a program that can do this?

Comment: GIMP can run Script-fu and Python-fu scripts - but don't ask me how to write one. I've no idea.

Answer (score 3):

A very basic python script that does it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gimpfu import *

def selectionMargins(image):
    selection,x1,y1,x2,y2=pdb.gimp_selection_bounds(image)
    if not selection:
        pdb.gimp_message("No selection")
    else:
        gimp.message('L=%d\nU=%d\nR=%d\nD=%d' % (x1,y1,image.width-x2,image.height-y2))

### Registration
desc='Show selection margins'
register(
    'selection-margins',desc,desc,'','','2019',desc,'*',
    [(PF_IMAGE, "image", "Input image", None),],[],
    selectionMargins,menu="<Image>/Select"
)

main()
```

- Copy the script to a text file with `.py` extension (note: python is sensitive to the indentation of the code)
- See Edit>Preferences>Folder>Plugins for the folder whre the resulting file should be
- On OSX and Linux, make it executable
- The menu entry is at the bottom of the `Select` menu in an image window.
- Output is in a dialog or in the error console window if it up

[image]

It wouldn't be difficult to improve the script to append to a CSV file a line with the image file name/path and the values.

Comment: Of course, very basic for you. I don't know this matter. I'm away from my computer right now. I'll try as soon as I get to the computer.

Comment: 5 lines of code, once you have removed the boilerplate :)